# css grid element inside flex element doesn't overflow container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a flex container, with 2 children.

one of them is set to `flex-grow: 1`, to take as much space as possible.
the other child will not fit to its content (and I've tried `flex-shrink: 0`), the content is a CSS grid.

[image]

How can I make both children have the minimum width of their respective content, while keeping the current structure where one child takes as much width as possible?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrjMgQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style is wrong

```css
ninja-manager .ninja-manager__not-active__inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
}
```

Since it gives to the columns 50% of the total width, and on the other hand you are setting a gap between columns. The total width that you have used is greater than the width available.

Change it to this, where you are using the available space after taking into account the gaps:

```css
ninja-manager .ninja-manager__not-active__inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
}
```

[forked codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZobJVZ)

Comment: thank you, I could have swear I tried that as well -)